# Interactive scatter plot between two variables in R without using shiny

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is it possible to create an interactive scatter plot between two variables (selected by user from multiple variables) in R, without using shiny. An example is [here](https://jjallaire.shinyapps.io/shiny-kmeans/)  using shiny. Is it possible to make such interactive plot without using shiny?(For example using Rmarkdown)

An example is here that use one button to select a variable using a button on plotly:

```
library(plotly)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 7:11, z = 10:14)

create_buttons <- function(df, y_axis_var_names) {
  lapply(
y_axis_var_names,
FUN = function(var_name, df) {
  button <- list(
    method = 'restyle',
    args = list('y'
                , list(df[, var_name]))
    ,        label = sprintf('Show %s', var_name)
  )
},
df
  )

}

y_axis_var_names <- colnames(df)

p <- plot_ly(df, x = ~x, y = ~y, mode = "markers", name = "A", visible = T) %>%
  layout(
title = "Drop down menus - Styling",
xaxis = list(title = "x"),
yaxis = list(title = "y"),
updatemenus = list(
  list(
    y = 0.7,
    buttons = create_buttons(df, y_axis_var_names)
  )
))
p
```

But I do not know how to add a second button to the second variable!

Comment: Would shiny runtime in Rmarkdown be an option? See [interactive documents](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/interactive-docs.html)

Comment: @Waldi, no, The example used shiny runtime. The output must be an html file like standard Rmarkdown can be execute in any device!

Comment: I think you could do it using `crosstalk`, though it's designed more for selection of cases rather than selecting columns to plot.

Comment: Another possibility is to include all possible plots in the web page, but set all but one of them to be invisible using Javascript code.

Comment: @user2554330, Both are reasonable!